# Cat urination problem

Tags: cats, behavior, urination

I have a cat urination behavior issue.

To start off, I used to feed a cat who avoids fighting with other cats and doesn't fight for food if another cat tries to steal from her. So I decided to take her in so I could take care of her when I was moving to another location. She is a year and 5 months old now, and I started feeding her when she was about 3 months old, so she's very used to being around me, and turns out to be a really friendly, loving house kitty. But she doesn't get along with one of my sister's 2 cats. She hisses and avoids the cat everytime she comes close.

To get started on the main question, my cat is very lovely and all but she pees on soft things randomly every now and then. She pees mainly on carpets, blankets, laundry, and basically anything soft and with cushion. However, she pees in litter boxes too and she never does the poopoo business outside of the litter box, meaning that she does know that that's where she takes care of her business.

I tried changing the litter sand, location of the litter boxes, and putting on a Comfort Zone diffuser, and did different things like adding nature related things in the litter box too, but she still pees on soft things. I think she does not like litter sands in general and I think she might be peeing somewhere other than litter box because she smells the things of my sister's cat in the litter boxes... does anybody have an idea how to fix this problem?

Thank you!!

Comment: Hey, you might want to ask about the sleeping as an independent question in it's own right since it doesn't really have anything to do with your primary query.